# How do I index this field in ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer

I want to index the following field:

```
quick brown fox
```

So that a search for exactly all 3 words, *in any order*, will hit, but a search for only a few of the words, (like 'brown fox'), will miss.

In other words, I want to create an index/query so the following is true:

```
# input for field
quick brown fox

# hits
brown fox quick
fox quick brown
quick brown fox
...

# misses
quick brown
fox
quick brown fox red
...
```

It seems like I'd have to make a custom tokenizer to do this. A tokenizer that explodes an input stream into these keyword permutations. I'm not sure where to begin. I'm using ruby/tire. Is that the right idea? How do I go about making my own tokenizer?

Comment: Can't you just use a match query with operator AND, so that all of the terms in the query must appear in the matching documents? The order would not count unless you make a query that takes into account positions like a phrase query or span query. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @javanna No, I don't think I can. If I understand you correctly, wouldn't a query for 'fox' match the field 'quick brown fox'? I'm trying to create an index where 'fox' doesn't match the field 'quick brown fox' as the user did not include `quick` or `brown` in the query. Make sense?

Comment: Right, I had the feeling I was missing something. Maybe you can make clearer in your question that those are queries that should or should not match the document. Don't know what the usecase is, anyways... yeah you do need to create your own tokenizer, not sure if you can achieve what you want combining the existing ones. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sort these words alphabetically, combine them together using some separator that couldn't appear in the words and index them as a single not analyzed token. So, `quick brown fox` would be indexed as `brown-fox-quick`. You would need to preform this operation during both indexing and searching. Ideally, this would be done by an analyzer, but I am not aware of any analyzers that would do something like this for you. So you need to write your own custom analyzer (as java plugin) or implement this logic in your code outside of elasticsearch.

Comment: Cool idea. I like the simplicity of ordering at index _AND_ query time  over my original thinking.